# C# Sending log to email after closing application

Tags: c#, email, nlog

I have some troubles with sending log to email using NLog. I need to NLog sends all errors to email after closing the application,not everytime when NLog is calling. Is it real to do it ?
There is code i am using :

```
<target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper"
          name="MailBuffer"
          slidingTimeout="false"
          bufferSize="100"
          flushTimeout="-1">
    <target name="HeelpAdsImport_patrick_email" xsi:type="Mail"
            smtpServer="XXXXX"
            smtpPort="25"
            smtpAuthentication="Basic"
            smtpUserName="YYYYYY"
            smtpPassword="*ZZZZZZ"
            enableSsl="false"
            from="DDDDDDDDDD"
            to="EEEEEEEEEEE"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${callsite:className=true:includeSourcePath=true:methodName=true} ${message}${newline}"
          />
</target>
```

Comment: What kind of troubles do you have exactly?

Comment: Is it OK to call a NLog method just before the application closes?

Comment: @romanoza , i need to send all errors to email,while application closes,not everytime when NLog is called.